# Assign value based on two other columns by partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing actions performed by a worker (action_ID, action_name, date/time, department, and shift_id). I want to create a column of shift_location, which can be determined based on the values of two other columns.

The shift location can be determined based on the Dept for Sort cart action during each shift.

| Action_ID | Action_Name | Action_DTTM | Dept | Shift_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Load cart | 11/01/2023 14:12:01 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | Sort cart | 11/01/2023 16:12:23 | Magenta | 1 |
| 3 | Distribute | 11/01/2023 16:17:14 | M | 1 |
| 4 | Load cart | 11/04/2023 11:12:51 | NULL | 2 |
| 5 | Sort cart | 11/04/2023 11:22:01 | Blue | 2 |
| 6 | Distribute | 11/04/2023 12:12:35 | B | 2 |
| 7 | Load cart | 11/05/2023 06:22:17 | NULL | 3 |
| 8 | Sort cart | 11/05/2023 08:19:21 | Magenta | 3 |
| 9 | Distribute | 11/05/2023 14:12:01 | M | 3 |

Desired output is

| Action_ID | Action_Name | Action_DTTM | Dept | Shift_ID | Shift_loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Load cart | 11/01/2023 14:12:01 | NULL | 1 | Magenta |
| 2 | Sort cart | 11/01/2023 16:12:23 | Magenta | 1 | Magenta |
| 3 | Distribute | 11/01/2023 16:17:14 | M | 1 | Magenta |
| 4 | Load cart | 11/04/2023 11:12:51 | NULL | 2 | Blue |
| 5 | Sort cart | 11/04/2023 11:22:01 | Blue | 2 | Blue |
| 6 | Distribute | 11/04/2023 12:12:35 | B | 2 | Blue |
| 7 | Load cart | 11/05/2023 06:22:17 | NULL | 3 | Magenta |
| 8 | Sort cart | 11/05/2023 08:19:21 | Magenta | 3 | Magenta |
| 9 | Distribute | 11/05/2023 14:12:01 | M | 3 | Magenta |

I thought about trying to use a case expression but didn't know how to make it look at two different columns, within a shift partition, to assign the location. I also thought about first value but didn't know how to make it find the first non-null dept in a shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a self JOIN, APPLY, or a scalar subquery, eg:

```
select t.*, sc.Dept Shift_Loc
from t
left join t sc
  on t.Shift_ID = sc.Shift_ID
  and sc.Action_Name = 'Sort Cart'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! It's really difficult as a noob to know where to start. Having someone tell me I just need a self join and how to join on two conditions is really helpful.